# Why I cant install powerline

Tags: vim

I've install powerline, but 'you complete me' always throws an error (I've tried Ubuntu 16.04 & Ubuntu 14.04 but have the same problem in both)

I've reinstall everything I can think of.

I use a script to run it

error message:

[image]

and when I get into vim there is also an error

## powerline install script:

```
if $POWERLINE; then
    echo "POWERLINE"

    # Install pip
    sudo apt-get install -y python-dev
    sudo apt-get install -y python-setuptools
    sudo apt-get install -y easy_install
    sudo easy_install pip

    # Install powerline
    sudo pip install powerline-status

    # Install git complete
    sudo apt-get install -y git bash-completion

    # Install Fonts
    wget https://github.com/powerline/powerline/raw/develop/font/PowerlineSymbols.otf
    wget https://github.com/powerline/powerline/raw/develop/font/10-powerline-symbols.conf
    mkdir -p ~/.fonts/
    mv PowerlineSymbols.otf ~/.fonts/
    fc-cache -vf ~/.fonts/
    mkdir -p ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/
    mv 10-powerline-symbols.conf ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/
fi
```

## rc file replacement script:

```
if $RC; then
    echo "RC"

    # Copy rc file
    sudo apt-get install -y vim
    sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake
    sudo apt-get install -y python-dev
    cp ./.vimrc ~
    cp ./.bashrc ~
    cp ./.bash_profile ~
    cp ./.screenrc ~

    # Install vim plugin
    git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
    vim +PluginInstall +qall
    cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
    ./install.py --clang-completer --omnisharp-completer --gocode-completer --tern-completer
fi
```